# Nh.Burrow with WCF

Tags: wcf, nhibernate, nhibernate-burrow

After implementing Nh.Burrow in an asp.net application, I was wondering how to do it for a WCF-service.

My first idea was to put a the `BurrowFramework().InitWorkSpace();` in each method and set the InstanceContextMode to per Call on these methods. Now I have two questions:

1. Are there better methods to combine Nh.Burrow with WCF?
2. Is there a way to create and use a Long Burrow Conversation with WCF?

Comment: I'm interested in this. Did you find more information?

Comment: I haven't found a better way for te moment. Doing InitWorkSpace in each service call is the simplest solution for now. But I still have to check UNHAddins.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [nhibernate addins project](http://code.google.com/p/unhaddins/). They've got WCF integration facilities like NhSessionPerCallContextBehavior as well as loads of other usefull stuff.